# ASP.NET conditional css class

Tags: asp.net

This piece of code works fine:

```
if (i == ViewBag.CurPageIndex)
{
  <a class="selectedPage" asp-controller="Home/Index" asp-route-id="@(i + 1)"> @pps[i] </a>
}
else
{
  <a asp-controller="Home/Index" asp-route-id="@(i + 1)"> @pps[i] </a>
}
```

but this one doesn't:

```
var c = "";
if (i == ViewBag.CurPageIndex) { c = "class=\"selectedPage\""; }
<a @c asp-controller="Home/Index" asp-route-id="@(i + 1)"> @pps[i] </a>
```

Comment: I don't see a question. Perhaps edit this post to include at least a question mark somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Your string probably is being concatenated wrongly, then you don't get the result you expect...you can either change your code like this:
`c = "class='selectedPage'";`

or try like this (it's even cleaner)

```
<a @(i == ViewBag.CurPageIndex ? "class='selectedPage'" : "") asp-controller="Home/Index" asp-route-id="@(i + 1)"> @pps[i] </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

The string *is* emitted after quoting the attribute value:

```
<a class=""selectedPage"" ...
```

The Razor engine doesn't know what `@c` refers to, it only sees a string that has to be cleaned up before emitting. It understands that `class="selectedPage"` is an attribute and treats what follows as a string, whether it contains quotes or not.

There are other problems too. The `asp-controller` attribute should contain the name of a controller, not a URL or the path to an action. The Razor engine *knows* this isn't a valid controller name , so it emits the attribute as is. Afer that, the Razor engine realizes that something weird is going on and simply emitts everything as is. The link ends up as :

```
<a class=""alert-danger"" asp-route-id="2" asp-controller="Home/Index"> b </a>
```

Removing the quotes would create a proper `class` value but the engine would still emit the otheer tags.

You should store only the class name in the `c` variable. The `asp-controller` tag should refer to the controller only. The action should be specified in the `asp-action` tag. This isn't needed in this case, as `Index` is the default.

The code should look like this:

```
if (i == ViewBag.CurPageIndex) { c = "selectedPage"; }
<a class=@c asp-controller="Home" asp-route-id="@(i + 1)"> @pps[i] </a>
```

or

```
<a class=@c asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index" asp-route-id="@(i + 1)"> @pps[i] </a>
```

Both will generate :

```
<a class="selectedPage" href="/Home/Index/2"> b </a>
```